# Не обнаруживаются переменные в useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Внутри хука useEffect объявил некоторые переменные, но реакт не видит их. Пытался передать в fetchData, не даёт. Возможно решение проблемы перед носом, но я хожу вокруг.

```
      useEffect(() => {
async function fetchData() {
  const cartResponse = await axios.get("https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/cart")
  const favoritesResponse = await axios.get("https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/favorites")
  const itemsResponse = await axios.get("https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/items")
}

setItems(itemsResponse.data);
setCartItems(cartResponse.data)
setFavorites(favoritesResponse.data)

fetchData();
}, []);
```

[image: Код и ошибка]

Comment: Перед носом. Переменные находятся вне области видимости сетеров. Перенесите сеты (`setItems`, `setCartItems`, `setFavorites` внутрь тела функции `fetchData`.

Comment: Спасибо большое) Бывает такое, что смотришь, вроде всё норм, а оказывается скобки закрывающей не могу увидеть

Answer (score 0):

async function fetchData() {
try {
const cartResponse = await axios.get('https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/cart')
await setCartItems(cartResponse.data)
const favoritesResponse = await axios.get('https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/favorites')
await setFavorites(favoritesResponse.data)
const itemsResponse = await axios.get('https://6257c564e4e0b7314280074d.mockapi.io/items')
await setItems(itemsResponse.data);
}catch (e) {
console.log(e)
}
}
useEffect(() => {
fetchData();
}, []);

Comment: Спасибо большое, а если визуально разбить мой код на две части: создание переменных и вызов функцией этих переменных, то где будет определяться порядок рендера: в части создания переменных или вызова функций